# How to set my value in input value in react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i want have only one onChange for several inputs in reacthooks so I did this

```
const [name, setName] = useState({  firstName: '', lastName: ''})
const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
 const {name, value} = event.target;
 setName({
   ...name,
   [name]: value,
 })
}
  <input
     type="text"
     name="fistName"
     value={firstNmae}
     onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
<input
     type="text"
     name="lastName"
     value={lastName}
     onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
```

It works right.but when my page is loding i get firstname and lastname  from API .I used to do this before I had a change:

```
 const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  await CmdTseService.getPersonInfo((status, data) => {
            personData = data.Result;
          }

  fetchData().then(() => {
   setFirstName(personData.FirstName);
        setLastName(personData.LastName);

})
```

Now how do I do this?

Comment: [Is this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-lovelace-kyuec?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't call the method `setName()`?

```js
setName({
  firstName: personData.FirstName,
  lastName: personData.LastName,
});
```